# Position based dynamics example (Matthias Müller)

Tags: c++, animation, physics, particles

I'm wondering if someone has a code example of position based dynamics with i.e. a spring constraint? I found this paper describing the technique which has some pseudo code, but I would love to see some java/c/c++/as/... code

http://www.matthiasmueller.info/publications/hpbd.pdf

Comment: "Spring constraint"? In the language of PBD a spring is not a constraint, it's part of f_ext. What have you tried coding so far?

Comment: @Beta That's not entirely the case. In the PBD model, ad hoc spring-like behavior is achieved by replacing the usual spring force with a spring or stretching "constraint", although that constraint may be only partially/fractionally enforced to approximate stretchy spring-like behaviour. For example, Muller's original paper models cloth using such constraints between vertices of the cloth (Fig 3.) The strength of the spring is handled using an iteration-dependent pseudo-stiffness parameter k that dials back the constraint projection (see the end of Section 3.3).

Comment: You should at least read the paper and try to understand the math and try some code, it is the only way you will learn the most.

Answer (score 4):

The soft body (and cloth/rope) simulation in the open source Bullet physics library is using position based dynamics, as described by Thomas Jakobsen ( http://www.gamasutra.com/resource_guide/20030121/jacobson_01.shtml) and your paper link by Matthias Mueller.

See http://bullet.googlecode.com for the C++ source code.

Comment: Actually, it may happen that Jakobsen's Hitman 1 engine is not the first to use that idea. It may have been actually _used_ by Xavier Provost in 1995, when he developed a cloth simulator.

Answer (score 1):

There is an updated source on google code that has the more direct implementation of this very idea. It's called the [OpenCloth](http://code.google.com/p/opencloth/wiki/Verlet_and_PBD) project and it truly is an awesome collection of various approaches neatly and simply implemented.

Answer (score 0):

[Processing](http://processing.org/) has various [physics](http://murderandcreate.com/physics/) and particle system [libraries](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/), and they use Java.

**Edit**: I guess I misunderstood the question earlier, but [here](http://www.somethingorotherwhatever.com/positionbased.bmx) is someone's attempt to code Muller's approach.